# How to access the environment of the function that started a Shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a *Shiny* application that I run by calling a function that calls `shiny::runApp`.  The application can access the global environment, therefore it can access to data in objects that have a name decided in advance.  However, I would like to pass it data through the parameters of the function that runs the app.  The following example works.

```
f <- function(param) {
  runApp(
    list(
      ui = fixedPage({
        verbatimTextOutput('text')
      }),
      server = function(input, output) {
        output$text <- renderPrint(param)
      })
  )
}

f("hello")
```

However, I can not reproduce this behaviour when the *ui* and *server* components are loaded from a file:

File contents:

```
$ cat ui.R 
fixedPage({
      verbatimTextOutput('text')
    })

$ cat server.R 
function(input, output) {
      output$text <- renderPrint(param)
    }
```

*R* code:

```
g <- function(param) {
  runApp()
}

g("hello")
```

Error message:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3870
Warning: Error in renderPrint: object 'param' not found
Stack trace (innermost first):
    86: renderPrint
    85: func
    84: eval
    83: eval
    82: withVisible
    81: evalVis
    80: utils::capture.output
    79: paste
    78: origRenderFunc
    77: output$text
     2: runApp
     1: g [#2]
```

I guess that it has something to do with the fact that the components are not created in similar scopes in the two examples, but I could not find a workaround...  In the second example, is there a way where I can access the environment of the function `g` from the Shiny app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Define the `param` object in the global environment:

```
g <- function(param) {
  assign("param",param,.GlobalEnv)
  runApp()
}
#this now works and print `hello` as intended
g("hello")
```

Comment: Thanks, I am now storing the name of the objects to retrieve through a global option; the launcher function (`g` in the example above) sets it before starting the app (for instance `getOption("myPackage.g" = "param")`, and the app retrieves the object from the global environment with a command such as `get(getOption("myPackage.g"), .GlobalEnv)`.